# Rails 4 Join query through has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I have a two models, posts and tags, with a many-to-many relationship between them. I have implemented this relationship with a posts_tags table with is formed of posts.post_id and tags.tag_id.

I'm trying to get an active record object of all posts with a certain tag. I have this working with the code:

```
posts_i_want = []
all = Post.all
all.each do |x|
    x.tags.each do |y|
        if y.tag == params[:tag]
            posts_i_want.push(x.id)
        end
    end
end
@posts = Post.where(id: posts_i_want)
```

But from reading on the subject it seems there is a much better way to do it. 
Something similar to:

```
@posts = Post.joins("INNER JOIN posts_tags ON posts.post_id = posts_tags.post_id INNER JOIN tags ON posts_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id WHERE tags.tag = #{params[:tag]}")
```

or

```
@posts = Post.joins(posts_tags: :tags).where(tag: params[:tag])
```

but i was unsuccessful in getting the proper way to work. I'm hoping someone experienced with ruby on rails can suggest what the solution might look like. Thanks!

p.s. using postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please

```
@posts = Post.joins(:posts_tags).where(posts_tags: { tag: params[:tag] })
```

EDIT: looking at you iterative code it seems you don't need the post_tags join. You actually need a tags join so

```
    @posts = Post.joins(:tags).where(tag: params[:tag])
```

Comment: Thanks for trying! but that returns an empty activerecord object. It doesn't crash though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

You want to do this:

```
@posts = Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: { tag: params[:tag] })
```

`joins(:tags)` pulls in the habtm association.

`{ tags: { ... } }` specifies the habtm association.

`{ tag: ... }` specifies the `tag` attribute on the `Tag` class (`Tag#tag`).

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score -1):

Your query should look like

```
@posts = Post.joins(:posts_tags).joins(:tags).where(tag: params[:tag])
```

or

```
@posts = Post.{name of relationship}.find_by(tag: params[:tag])
```

Comment: He doesn't actually need to join posts_tags though as it looks like he has a has many through relationship already, just joining tags should be more than suffice